# Error while creating Business data connectivity service in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating a new Business data connectivity service in SharePoint 2010.I have given the Database Server name (eg: PC40 in my LAN) and Database Name (eg:test). When I clicked OK, got an error.

```
The timer job completed, but failed on one or more machines in the farm.
```

See if i am creating a new external content type in sharepoint designer how can i configure/save it under my new Business data connectivity service?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the ULS or Event Viewer on the servers when you try to do this?

Comment: @JohnChapman I have verified the log and found error "The server was not found or was not accessible".I changed the server name and it is working fine now..I have one more doubt.I am using designer to create external content type.When i saves it, always comes under default Business Data Connectivity service. How can i configure/save it under my new custom Business data connectivity service?

Answer (score 1):

For the BCS service make it so the desired BCS service is marked as default for the service proxy group the web application is associated with in Central Administration.

Comment: Here is info about the proxy groups: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704550.aspx